# Can I allow my friend to Family Share a game I own and use via Family Sharing another friend's copy [of the same game]?

Tags: steam

Lets say I want to play Counter Strike on Steam. But my friend doesnt own this game. So I share my libary with my friend. Now my friend is able to play it.

Now the complex part. When I want to play with him and i have other friends which own Counter Strike, how can i be able to use their shared Counter Strike? So My friend is using my CS while I use another CS.

I already tried out to go on my friends profile to open CS in that way, but i cannot find anything.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not totally mistaken, this isn't possible.

You can't play shared games from other peoples libraries when you have that game yourself. Thus, your friend can't play CS when you're playing it.

Keep in mind, that family sharing is to allow others to test-play your games in hopes they will buy it afterwards. Not to enable you to play your games with friends.

Comment: Your friend can't play ANY games from your library when you're playing ANY game in your library.  Doesn't even have to be the same game. i.e. me starting up Team Fortress 2 would kick out a friend playing Plants vs. Zombies that I'm sharing.

Comment: @Powerlord, you could always do the account switcheroo.

Answer (score 2):

## Actually...

**Yes, it is possible.** But it involves using a loophole in the family sharing system.
Just remember that your first gaming owning friend cannot play on his account without kicking you off.

**What you'll need:**

- Two alternate accounts (They do not have to have anything owned on them)
- Two accounts that own the game in question.

**What do you do:**

1. On each computer that you want to play, log into the alternate accounts at least once.
2. Setup Steam Guard on both accounts as accounts are ineligible for family sharing **if** they do not have Steam Guard.
3. Log into the accounts that has the game in question.
4. Authorise your current computer for Family Sharing and authorise the alternate accounts you created.
5. Log out of the accounts that own the game on both computers.
6. Start playing on the alternate accounts!

**Side note:** *This only applies to the OP's case.*
Since you're playing Counter-Strike: Global Offensive, weapon skins and matchmaking is unavailable to those who do not own the game, or are playing via family sharing. However, you'll still be able to connect to your own server, if you create one.

## For your case:

**Note:** Just to not confuse with who is who, let's say your friend who owns CS:GO and isn't playing is **Friend 1** and the one who doesn't own but wants to play is **Friend 2**.

1. Both you and Friend 2, create an alternate account and setup Steam Guard.
2. Both you and Friend 2 then log into your alternate accounts... Then log out.
3. Get Friend 1's credentials and log into his account.
4. Give Friend 2 your credentials and get him to log into your account.
5. Both you and Friend 2 then go into **Settings > Family > Family Sharing**.
6. Both you and Friend 2 then authorize the current computer and the alternate accounts.
7. Both you and Friend 2 then log out of the accounts that own the game and log into your own corresponding alternate accounts.
8. Start playing [on the alternate accounts].

## Alternatively

Can't you just use your friend-who-owns-the-game's account while your friend-who-does-not-own-the-game uses your account?

Comment: Further to this excellent answer... the simple solution would be to get the friend to save up and spend the $15US on a copy. It cost even less in the recent Steam Sale. You don't even need a credit/debit card these days, go to any game shop and buy a $20 steam wallet card. Or sell some skins on CS:GO and use the proceeds to buy the friend a copy. Plenty of options other than dealing with account sharing woes...

Answer (score -1):

I don't 100% know if this works yet, but my buddy lent me his steam info when I logged into his, I noticed his games and my games that he didn't own. So what I did was install some of his games on my cpu and went back to my account, and so far they are downloading correctly.

Comment: They are not DRM-free if they are on steam. I do not think they will let you play since they are not owned by you.

Comment: ok so i tried this out but it did not work but u can still play on their account

Answer (score -3):

> Can I share Counter-Strike: Global Offensive through Steam Family Library Sharing?
>   Counter-Strike: Global Offensive can be shared through Steam Family Library Sharing; however, a borrowed version will only have access to certain features of the full game. 
>   Shared versions of the game will not be eligible for item drops nor have access to the in-game inventory.
>
> Competitive matchmaking and the spectator client will also only be available in the full game.
>
> For access to the full game purchase Counter-Strike: Global Offensive from the Steam Store page below:
>   http://store.steampowered.com/app/730/
>
> For more information about Steam Family Library Sharing, please see the Users Guide